# Bezier Curve (Quadratic, Cubic) stroke triangulation on GPU using OpenGL 4.4

Tags: opengl, gpu, bezier

How, given only control points, generate triangulation of bezier curve stroke hull (possibly with minimal area) with given stroke width using OpenGL 4.4 features like compute, tessellation, geometry and vertex shaders.

Comment: @Wilbert Can you add some direction points how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Maybe you want to rephrase your question? As it stands currently, you only ask for a yes/no answer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman This is not what I was looking for. They utilize fragments shaders to render curves. I am interested in generating hull of offset curves and triangulate this hull on GPU.

Comment: Oh, so what you *actually* want is GPU accelerated path rendering? If you have an NV GPU, there is an OpenGL extension for that. If you do not want to limit yourself to NV, there is also OpenVG or Direct2D.

Answer (score 2):

"OpenGL SuperBible" 6th edition chapter 8 and "OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook" chapter 6 have examples of how to tessellate cubic Beziers on the GPU.